# Updates in Admob - Missing

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I have 2 android app in Google Play. One with the Old Admob SDK and another one with the Google play services (to access Admob). For the past 1 day, I do not receive any updates in their Sites & Apps page. Anything strange ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22755933/admob-reports-requests-and-revenue-is-stop

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a support issue for Admob, not a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same with me.
After done searched a lot, and finally found that this usually happening few time a year. 
So, do not worries... Just let's wait.

Answer (score 0):

It was last updated on 2014-03-29 00:00:00 GMT.Nothing strange. It happens several time in a year.

I thinks it should be fine in another day or so.